# Set focus to the EditText upon clicking a button

Tags: java, android, user-interface

```
int[] etColorId = new int[] {R.id.etColor1, R.id.etColor2, R.id.etColor3, R.id.etColor4, R.id.etColor5,
            R.id.etColor6, R.id.etColor7, R.id.etColor8, R.id.etColor9, R.id.etColor10, R.id.etColor11,
            R.id.etColor12, R.id.etColor13, R.id.etColor14, R.id.etColor15};
    
    for (int editText : etColorId) {
        findViewById(editText).setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                v.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }
    
    int[] btnEditId = new int[] {R.id.btnEdit1, R.id.btnEdit2, R.id.btnEdit3, R.id.btnEdit4, R.id.btnEdit5,
            R.id.btnEdit6, R.id.btnEdit7, R.id.btnEdit8, R.id.btnEdit9, R.id.btnEdit10, R.id.btnEdit11,
            R.id.btnEdit12, R.id.btnEdit13, R.id.btnEdit14, R.id.btnEdit15};
    
    for (int button : btnEditId) {
        findViewById(button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                v.setEnabled(true);
                v.requestFocus();
            }
        });
    }
```

How can I gain focus to EditText upon clicking a button? I have a bunch of EditTexts and Buttons. Each button corresponds to a specific EditText. What I want is, for example: if I clicked the button1, the EditText1 will be focused. And then when I click other button, the EditText corresponds to that button will be focused and then the other EditTexts will be disabled.

Comment: use et.requestFocus() in onClickListener() method of that button

Comment: How can I use .requestFocus() If my ID's are in Array?

Comment: @CarloDacuyan see the answer, i posted

Comment: I'm on it, @Akhil Jain. I will let you know when it works!

Comment: @CarloDacuyan dont post the answer back in question

Comment: Okay. Will delete it now!

Comment: Where should I put it though?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code for `OnFocusChangeListener` has to be modified little bit, for anonymous classes you need to have final reference of any object which you wish to modify, since you want to modify `EditText`

```
final int[] etColorId = new int[] {R.id.etColor1, R.id.etColor2, R.id.etColor3, R.id.etColor4, R.id.etColor5,
            R.id.etColor6, R.id.etColor7, R.id.etColor8, R.id.etColor9, R.id.etColor10, R.id.etColor11,
            R.id.etColor12, R.id.etColor13, R.id.etColor14, R.id.etColor15};
```

Now for `OnClickListener` do like this

```
for (int i=0;i<btnEditId.length;i++) 
{
    final int counter=i;
    int button=btnEditId[i];
    findViewById(button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            // HERE v refers to button itself on which you clicked, 
            // you need to update get edit text so
            // based on ith position accessing the same edit as the button correspond too
            EditText edt=etColorId[counter];
            edt.setEnabled(true);
            edt.requestFocus();
            // and you are DONE!!!
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
 new OnFocusChangeListener() 
 {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
            {

                if(!hasFocus) 
                { // lost focus
                       v.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    //you are already enabling on button click
                }
            }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Akhil Jain. Your code does really help. The button now works the way it is. All I need to finish now is how the onFocusChange works. PS: Ty for the update, will analyze it.

Answer (score 4):

Inside

```
onClick()
{
    edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    edittext.requestFocus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

onFocusChange called every time when lost focus and gain focus.

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    v.setEnabled(false);
}
```

So, first you need to change code

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(hasFocus) {// gain focus
       // Code block
    }
    if(!hasFocus) { // lost focus
        // Code block
    }
}
```

You `EditText` is disabled every time, when press `Button`

Comment: Thanks for this @Palak. Will take a loot at it!